# MySQL- comparing two rows by language id - find rows where translation doesn't exist

Tags: php, mysql, sql, translation

everyone!

I've got this table, where I keep categories and each translation is a new row with a different language_id.

```
categories_id   language_id     categories_name
8032            4               Dukke
8032            10              Doll
8029            10              Bike
8074            4               Bil
```

I would like to fetch those rows that doesn't have a translation for language_id 4 or language_id 10. So in this case, the output would be something like this:

```
categories_id   language_id     categories_name
8029            10              Bike
8074            4               Bil
```

The end result in frontend would be a list like this:

```
TRANSLATION 1 - TRANSLATION 2
Bike - [add translation]
[add translation] - Bil
```

Comment: `select id, category_name, language_id
from your_table
group by id, category_name, language_id
having count(*) < 2`

Comment: show your code ..

Comment: How many languages are there, more than 2?

Comment: @jeroen Just two for the moment

Comment: This all is from the single table ??

Comment: @Susang Yeah, all from a single table :-)

Comment: @scaisEdge Well, I really showed what code I have.

Comment: You accept my answer, then ask another question with the same request with the reason that you didn't find an answer here. You remove the accepted flag, even if my query does what you have requested yesterday. And now you change the sample data here, decide what you want mate!

Answer (score 1):

**UPDATE**

A better solution will be to pivot the table; In case that you will have more languages you just need to add the `CASE WHEN ... END` statements for the new ones

```
SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT
        category_id
        ,MAX(CASE WHEN lang_id = 10 THEN category_name end) AS Translation_1
        ,MAX(CASE WHEN lang_id = 4 THEN category_name end) AS Translation_2
    FROM (SELECT category_id, category_name, lang_id from tbl) t
    group by category_id) t
WHERE Translation_1 is null OR Translation_2 is null
```

Try it [**here**](http://rextester.com/YMO69642).

Comment: This pointed me in the right direction, I think.

I'm currently getting this result:

8026 Stel m.m. Stel m.m.
8026 Stel m.m. Ramar etc.

I only need it like this though:

8026 Stel m.m. Ramar etc.

And only where one of the two rows are empty, so something like this


8026 (empty here) Ramar etc.

Comment: I have and I'm afraid it doesn't work as expected - It returns a bunch of "false positives". Getting a bunch of id's where the translation actually exists

Comment: @DennisA Oh I see ... problem solved mate! I have updated the pivot query.

Answer (score 0):

If there are only 2 languages, you can join the table on itself.

Something like:

```
SELECT 
  t1.ID, t1.CATEGORY_NAME, t2.CATEGORY_NAME
FROM your_table t1
LEFT JOIN your_table t2
  ON t1.ID = t2.ID
WHERE t1.LANGUAGE_ID = 1
  AND t2.ID IS NULL
```

For more languages, you would have to do something similar multiple times.

Comment: Thank you! Sadly, it didn't work. I get zero returned results.

Comment: @DennisA Are you sure the ID's are the same for both languages? It looks strange, having duplicate ID's...

Comment: Aye, I'm positive!

Answer (score 0):

**TRY THIS:** It should work for you, collect the primary language id using `subquery` with `MIN` of every category id then join with the same table with same `ID` and min `language_id` of category to retrieve the primary translation which is `TRANSLATION_1` then again join with same `ID` but `not equal to` `language_id` to retrieve `TRANSLATION_2` AND check the condition if `language_id IS NULL` as below:

```
SELECT t.id, 
    t1.category_name AS TRANSLATION_1, 
    t2.category_name AS TRANSLATION_2
FROM (SELECT ID, MIN(language_id) language_id FROM test GROUP BY ID) t
LEFT JOIN test t1 ON t1.id = t.id 
    AND t1.language_id = t.language_id
LEFT JOIN test t2 ON t2.id = t.id 
    AND t2.language_id <> t.language_id
WHERE (t1.language_id IS NULL OR t2.language_id IS NULL)
```

**OUTPUT:** --IF one of language is NULL

```
id  category_name   category_name
7   Dolls           NULL
```

Comment: I don't need that output, though. That's the problem. I need it with where one of the two category_names are empty.

Comment: Try it now, updated answer will surely meet your requirement.

Comment: This seems to be the closest answer so far :-) I'm trying to fiddle around with it to give me the correct result

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by generating *all* possible rows with words and languages.  Then remove the ones that do not exist:

```
select c.category_name, l.language_id
from (select distinct category_name from t) c cross join
     (select distinct language_id from t) l left join
     t
     on t.category_name = c.category_name and t.language_id = l.language_id
where t.category_name is null;
```

Comment: I'm afraid that's not what I need - Read the question again, please

Comment: @DennisA . . . This gives you all categories with all missing translations.  That seems to be what you are asking for.

Comment: It's not though - As I mention, I don't need the rows without translations removed - I specially need to keep those as empty fields.